# jquery find and replace with found html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do the following, is it possible to do this without using a `.filter` or `.each`

I have a row in a table that contains `select` and `input` elements. I am wanting to get the html from those and replace the input or select with just the value. so it would change from:

`<td><select>sometext</select></td>`

to

`<td>sometext</td>`

I have tried this, but it does nto seem to be working:

`$(this).find('select').replaceWith($(this).find('select').html());`

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `<select>sometext</select>` is invalid HTML

Comment: Thats not the way to asign a value, read jquery guide from the begin!

Comment: that was psuedo code I know that is not valid html.....

Answer (score 0):

```
   <td><select>sometext</select></td>
```

Is not valid in Html. But if you want, try this

```
   $('td').html($('select',this).html());
```

Comment: As long as `this` is not a document/node element or a jQuery object, then it is something else, so `$('select',this)` could result in an empty result set. At least you cannot assume that it is in an `.each` callback as the OP does not want to use it.

Comment: html is psuedo code in this example, tryignt o make the point that I have a <select> and want to remove it keeping the html as the html of the parent

Answer (score 0):

Currently your HTML markup is invalid, you can use `<span>` instead of `<select>`:

```
<td><span>sometext</span></td>
```

then you can apply **[.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)**:

```
$('td span').unwrap();
```

Comment: html is psuedo code in this example, tryignt o make the point that I have a `<select>` and want to remove it keeping the html as the html of the parent